# Specifying different percisions in Pandas saving functions

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
  1 import pandas as pd
  2 
  3 values = {
  4     'Name': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  5     'Val': [1.2341467, 12, 10000234.01]}
  6 
  7 df = pd.DataFrame(values)
  8 
  9 print(df)
 10 df.to_csv("pandastest.csv")
```

**Output**

```
,Name,Val
0,a,1.2341467
1,b,12.0
2,c,10000234.01
```

While saving to CSV sometimes I may have various types of data formats. Considering the above example perhaps I would like `a` to be formated as `1.23`, `b` to be formated as `12` and `c` to be formated as `1.0e7`. However, there is only as single format option while saving which forces all values to be the same

```
  1 import pandas as pd
  2 
  3 values = {
  4     'Name': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  5     'Val': [1.2341467, 12, 10000234.01]}
  6 
  7 df = pd.DataFrame(values)
  8 
  9 print(df)
 10 df.to_csv("pandastest.csv", float_format='%.2f')
 11
```

**Output**

```
,Name,Val
0,a,1.23
1,b,12.00
2,c,10000234.01
```

Is there a way to pass a dictionary or a list of formats to `float_format` to change the number of significant digits independently?

Answer (score 0):

No. The float_format parameter is str(or None) only. You will need to build something that modifies the data either in the DataFrame or in the CSV.